# Cannot Install Ubuntu 12.04.3LTS

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, system-installation, windows-8

I am having installation problem on Asus K55VD laptop.I selected `Install Ubuntu alongside Windows 8` and after clicking to `Continue` it restarts my laptop and I cannot install Ubuntu.

Comment: I think you tried to install in UEFI mode. Let's some more details to your question. What errors e.t.c?

Comment: yes i have tried to install UEFI mode.when it display 3 option for installation like along side windows 8,Replace wondows 8 with Ubuntu and somthing else.

Comment: selecting first option and continue.It will reboot my laptop with displaying the terminal window with some messages..

Comment: Can you use the "Try Ubuntu" option? Does that work?

Comment: You can't do it automatically like that with Windows 8 and UEFI. Follow the above directions.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do install alongside windows instead install seperately on another Partition using a live USB this will install a grub menu first then you will be able to get the windows and Ubuntu both working because windwos 8 overwrites the MBR make partitions with windows as you will know exactly what are you doing...